# SQL Server 2005 - DATE ADD AND GETDATE DOESN'T WORK

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a very strange error in a SQL query and I don't understand why.

```
SELECT 
    CODCLIFOR, '', 
    DSCCONTO1, '',  
    NUMDOC, '', 
    NUMSCAD, '', 
    DATASCADENZA, '', 
    REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, CAST(IMPORTOSCLIT AS money), 105),',','.') , '', 
    BANCAAPPCF.BANCAAPPOGGIO, '',
    TIPIEFFETTI.DESCRIZIONE
FROM 
    dbo.TABSCADENZE
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.ANAGRAFICACF ON CODCLIFOR = CODCONTO
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.TIPIEFFETTI ON TIPOEFFETTO = EFFETTO
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.BANCAAPPCF ON CODCLIFOR = BANCAAPPCF.CODCONTO AND BANCAAPPCF.CODICE = TABSCADENZE.BANCAAPPOGGIO
WHERE    
    TIPOEFFETTO = 2  
    AND DATASCADENZA ='2016-08-05' 
    AND CODCLIFOR LIKE '%C%'
ORDER BY 
    BANCAAPPCF.BANCAAPPOGGIO DESC
```

On date `DATASCADENZA` in the where condition, if I put the today date like '2016-08-05' I get results.. instead if I use `GETDATE()` or `DATEADD(DAY, 3, GETDATE())` I get no results... I don't understand why.

Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever look at what `GETDATE` returns?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`GETDATE()` returns the time component of the date.  In SQL Server 2005, you can remove the time component by doing:

```
DATASCADENZA = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

You can add three days as:

```
DATASCADENZA = DATEADD(day, 3 + DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

Starting in SQL Server 2008, you can just convert to the `DATE` data type:

```
DATASCADENZA = CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)
```

I much prefer this formulation to adding days to some mysterious "0" date.